# how to loopover rows in R to split the column based on respective values in adjacent column?

Tags: r

I have data frame with two columns as characters:

```
col1              col2
"Chharodi"       "Jasmine Green-1, Chharodi,Ravalvas, Chharodi,Thakorvas, Chharodi"
"Lapkaman"       "Belavyu Farm, Lapakaman,Ravalvas, Lapakaman,Vankarvas, Lapakaman"
"Ognaj"          "Vav Valo Vas, Oganaj,Marutinadan Society, Oganaj,Ravalvas,Ognaj"
```

I want to split the col2 with this out put (splitting the text based on adjacent value in col1):

```
col3                  col4                    col5          col_contd..
Jasmine Green-1      Ravalvas                Thakorvas
Belavyu Farm         Ravalvas                Vankarvas
Vav Valo Vas         Marutinadan Society     Ravalvas
```

get an error of 'non-character argument' when i use this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df1<-strsplit(df, df$col2[i],split = df$col1[i])
}
```

Also, how do I bind the rows together to create final df?

Comment: I just edited the data part to have better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `base R`, where `substring()` is used to extract chars in designated positions:

```
z <- lapply(df[,2], function(v) (x <- unlist(strsplit(v,split = ",")))[seq(1,length(x),by = 2)])

df.out <- `names<-`(r<-data.frame(df,lapply(z, `length<-`,max(lengths(z)))), 
                    paste0("col",seq(ncol(r))))
```

which gives

```
> df.out
      col1                                                             col2            col3         col4                col5
1 Chharodi Jasmine Green-1, Chharodi,Ravalvas, Chharodi,Thakorvas, Chharodi Jasmine Green-1 Belavyu Farm        Vav Valo Vas
2 Lapkaman Belavyu Farm, Lapakaman,Ravalvas, Lapakaman,Vankarvas, Lapakaman        Ravalvas     Ravalvas Marutinadan Society
3    Ognaj  Vav Valo Vas, Oganaj,Marutinadan Society, Oganaj,Ravalvas,Ognaj       Thakorvas    Vankarvas            Ravalvas
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("Chharodi", "Lapkaman", 
"Ognaj"), col2 = c("Jasmine Green-1, Chharodi,Ravalvas, Chharodi,Thakorvas, Chharodi", 
"Belavyu Farm, Lapakaman,Ravalvas, Lapakaman,Vankarvas, Lapakaman", 
"Vav Valo Vas, Oganaj,Marutinadan Society, Oganaj,Ravalvas,Ognaj"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @KirpalSingh Does this code work? The second line is to fill in the missing position with `NA` and rename the column names of data frame

Comment: the 2nd line gives me - Error in data.frame():arguments imply differing number of rows: 4419, 1260. My data has 4419 rows.

Comment: @KirpalSingh I updated my solution according to your newly posted data. See my edit

Comment: arguments imply differing number of rows: 4419, 178 - similar error as above. How do i label the first column with approx 4000 rows? I noticed, you labelled it in df with factor as class. can that be cause of error?

Comment: @KirpalSingh Yes, if it is factor, then there might be errors or incorrect result. My code is to process the `col2`, so I assume `col2` are not factors, It does not matter if `col1` is factor or not. To keep consistency, I removed the factor attribute for `col1` (see my edited `DATA`)...Did you try my data to run the code?

Comment: yes, your code works on your df! I will check the structure of my data.

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution,

```
i1 <- max(lengths(strsplit(as.character(df$col2), df$col1)))
do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$col2), df$col1), 
                                    function(i){length(i) <- i1; i}))


#     [,1] [,2]  [,3] 
#[1,] "l " " m " " n "
#[2,] "k " " g " " m "
#[3,] "e " " f " NA
```

Comment: I'm getting 'Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'i1' not found'. Why this would be?

Comment: I get 2nd column as it is in the form of matrix.

Comment: what do you mean? You can convert to `data.frame` If needed with `as.data.frame()`

Comment: 'as it is' without any change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option where we split the 'col2', `filter` out the matching elements with 'col1' and 'col2' and reshape to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    separate_rows(col2) %>%
    filter(col1 != col2) %>%
    group_by(col1) %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = col2) %>%
    select(-col1) %>%
    rename_all(~ str_c("col", 3:5))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   col3  col4  col5 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 l     m     n    
#2 k     g     m     
#3 e     f     <NA>
```

---

Or using `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
read.table(text = str_replace_all(df$col2, df$col1, ''),
    header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, col.names = paste0("col", 3:5))
#  col3 col4 col5
#1    l    m    n
#2    k    g    m
#3    e    f
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("x", "y", "z"), col2 = c("l x m x n x", 
"k y g y m y", "e z f z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: the filter option gives - Error: Unknown columns. The str_replace_all gives me file with multiple columns without considering col1 as replacement. I have posted actual sample data, it may help.

Comment: @KirpalSingh  I used your data in the post and it is not showing any error for me

Comment: I realized eventually the data structure is different in many rows including multiple commas/text between reference variable in col2. I finally used colsplit along with  str_extract_all. It worked but results are not 100% accurate. I'm working to increase the accuracy by cleaning the data.

Comment: @KirpalSingh  This is based on the pattern you showed